# Login to my app

Tags: security, user-accounts

I build an app that to each user will have is id and have a profile like (name, age email,location.....).

I thought to do with it the facebook id, but there is the problem that there are users without facebook account,so i thought to give users without a facebook account a unique id.

But here i have a problem that i don't have an answer on this. If i want that a user will be able to edit his profile details , i want to do it by sending a webrequest to my server and in the service i should edit the details by the user request.

The issue is that every user that know how to make this requests can listen to my app HTTP requests and send http requests to my server and change the profile of each user.

My question is if there is any other thing to handle my issue, or this is the only way.

Comment: You will need to send information to a server but you don't have to send plain text, un encrypted information. You should investigate secure web communication

Comment: I wrote that i try to use http requests that any user can do sniffing and see how they work, so i want to know if my only option is to use secure web communication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your data to be send securely to server, you need to do encryption, i.e. making plain text encrypted.
For this you can use hashing algorithm for validating key between transfer where you key can be anything secret which is randomly generated such as SHA512 algorithm which is only one step encryption i.e. cannot be decrypted.
Another option is use two way encryption and decryption such as AES256. [Here](http://pastie.org/426530) is nice tutorial on same

Hope this info helps you..

Comment: I found the way the SHA512 hashing from my send data, but the question if i can to the back side in the .net service?

Comment: the way you create your SHA512 encrypted string in iOS, same way you have to create SHA512 encrypted string on server and then just you need to match them both. Your encrypted string can be parameters with timestamp or some secret code.

Comment: Ok,There is any good site that do it online? that i can see how it work?

Comment: I saw this site,but i didn't saw how it's look the reverse way from the hash to the original string

Comment: Its hashing algorithm, you cannot get back your plain text back. Use AES256, I have mentioned tutorial link there for iOS